# Pandas - Cumulative sum for each unique id

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I need to cumulative sum for each unique id, my df:

```
  id   date       num 
0 4124 01.03.2021 3607
1 2155 01.03.2021 3500
2 1258 01.03.2021 2000
3 1112 01.03.2021 5000
4 1258 01.03.2021 3200
```

Result:

```
  id   date       num  RESULT
0 4124 01.03.2021 3607 3607
1 2155 01.03.2021 3500 3500
2 1258 01.03.2021 2000 2000
3 1112 01.03.2021 5000 5000
4 1258 01.03.2021 3200 5200
```

Trying smth like this, but it's doesn't work

```
def grouper(x):
    d = x.rename('id').to_frame().reset_index()
    return d.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='id')).cumcount()


df['RESULT'] = df.groupby(['id']).transform(grouper)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['RESULT'] = df['num'].groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
```

Result:

|  | id | date | num | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4124 | 01.03.2021 | 3607 | 3607 |
| 1 | 2155 | 01.03.2021 | 3500 | 3500 |
| 2 | 1258 | 01.03.2021 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1112 | 01.03.2021 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 4 | 1258 | 01.03.2021 | 3200 | 5200 |

Comment: wow, much easier than I thought, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda function for that:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row : sum(df[df.id == row['id']]['num']) , axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
      id    date        num    Result
0   4124    01.03.2021  3607    3607
1   2155    01.03.2021  3500    3500
2   1258    01.03.2021  2000    5200
3   1112    01.03.2021  5000    5000
4   1258    01.03.2021  3200    5200
```